# How can I do the configuration between React Native 0.60.0 and react-native-carplay?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, carplay

How can I do the configuration between React Native 0.60.0 and react-native-carplay?

I'm following example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-carplay but I'm receiving error on Xcode. I think that is fault of the changes of new version.
I would like use current version. Can someone help me?

Adding `#import #import <RNCarPlay.h>` on AppDelegate.m
Error => 'RNCarPlay.h' file not found

Adding methods before @end

- `(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didConnectCarInterfaceController:(CPInterfaceController *)interfaceController toWindow:(CPWindow *)window {
  [RNCarPlay connectWithInterfaceController:interfaceController window:window];
  }`
- `(void)application:(nonnull UIApplication *)application didDisconnectCarInterfaceController:(nonnull CPInterfaceController *)interfaceController fromWindow:(nonnull CPWindow *)window {
  [RNCarPlay disconnect];
  }`

Error => Use of undeclared identifier 'RNCarPlay'

```
import { CarPlay, GridTemplate } from 'react-native-carplay';

const template = new GridTemplate({ /* .. */ });

CarPlay.setRootTemplate(template, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered some things ...
Some steps didn't described on documentation.

In XCode, in the project navigator, right click Libraries ➜ Add Files to [your project's name]

Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-carply and add SplashScreen.xcodeproj

In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libSplashScreen.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With Libraries

To fix 'RNSplashScreen.h' file not found, you have to select your project → Build Settings → Search Paths → Header Search Paths to add:

$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-carplay/ios

After this change the error is resolved.